# How do I can change contents of some div sections while clicking text from another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

How do I can change contents of some div sections while clicking text from another div.The changing contents must be same as the clicked content.For example,if i have  3  as list

```
 <div id="text1">Text</div>

 <div id="text2">Text</div>

 <div id="text3">Text</div>
```

and another  where is the selected text should appear:

```
 <div id="textChanger">Content from #List</div>
```

Comment: Did you try something ?

Comment: sorry edited my question, wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Surely one of the first things you learn with jQuery is clicking elements? So do you even know what jQuery is? Simply go to youtube and type in **(jQuery or Javascript) Tutorial** That will be the first thing you learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/S6tFW/)

```
$('#text1').click(function () {
    $('#text2').text($(this).text());
});
```

[**id-selector**](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

[**.text()**](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

`$('#text1')` --> element with id `text`

`$(this)` refer to the current element

`$(this).text()` refers to the `text` inside the current element

`$('#text2').text($(this).text())` -->element with id `text2` is added with the `text` from id `text1`

updated code after OP updated question

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/S6tFW/2)

```
$('#List div[id^="text"]').click(function () {
    $('#textChanger').text($(this).text());
});
```

[attribute-equals-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

[^ **attribute-starts-with-selector**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: +1 for trying to explain the jQuery basics for OP.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$('#text1').on('click',function(){
    $('#text2').text($(this).text());
});
```